# How do I use SQLite in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm using phoneGap desktop and following examples of how to create and use SQLite - up till now most plugin code examples on the npm official cordova plugins page tell us what is required in config.xml - however examples keep showing how to reference plugins like cordova-sqlite-plugin, with the CLI  - as I'm new to phoneGap - I cant work out how to reference or even get the plugin since its not a standard cordova plugin in the config.xml file.

Most of the code examples are straight forward but assume the CLI - Where do you start if you're using phoneGap with the new phoneGap desktop App and intend to use phoneGap build? I have node and npm installed on my dev machine which is Windows. Do I follow the CLI instructions and download the plugin via the command line? In which case how do I use it in my phoneGap app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe even when using the Phonegap Desktop app, you still add plugins with the CLI.

Try `phonegap plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` or `cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` in your project.

You could also add the following to your config.xml.

```
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~0.8.5" />
```

Comment: where would i add either of those lines noting that i dont have the CLI installed i only have access to config.xml in the project

Comment: With phonegap desktop as stated in my thread  - the config.xml file was created with the skeleton program and includes all the official phonegap cordova plugins - just need to know how to add a non cordova plugin like SQL

Comment: I've added what the config.xml entry should look like. Phonegap will pull in the plugin when you run the build command in the CLI or build using phonegap build.

Comment: tried that in my config.xml but made no difference - but copied my code to a new project with the only difference being i'm using the xui.js library instead of jquery and hey presto the DB functions are working now without any reference needed. Not sure whats going on here but im happy anyway - thanks for your help however.